# Delete query where data in a table doesn't exist on a different table

Tags: php, sql

A typical query to delete table rows are usually like this, right?

```
$query1 = odbc_exec($conn, "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE uname1 <> uname2");
```

But what if I want it in such a way that `uname2` is in a different table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE uname1 NOT IN (
    SELECT uname2
    FROM table2
)
```

Comment: Yes, the data type doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

If `uname1` is unique, you could do something like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE uname1 NOT IN (
    SELECT uname2
    FROM table2 AS t2
    WHERE t2.uname1 = t1.uname1
);
```